# Form animation in a material design themed form

Tags: html, css, material-design

After having had a look at many many codepen material design forms, I found their basic HTML structure to be

```
 <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"><span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email"><span class="bar"></span>
    <label>Email</label>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="button buttonBlue">Subscribe
    <div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div>
  </button>
</form>
<br>
```

**[Example Codepen](http://codepen.io/Akashlal/pen/yOjBWV)**

In short, the `<input>` is always above the `<label>`

What `CSS` I need to modify, to make sure that the output remains the same, when the `<label>` is above the `<input>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using material design then no need to write custom CSS they already given demo for that.

For solution refer following link https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input

Here is sample code

```
<form name="userForm">
        <div layout-gt-xs="row">
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-xs>
            <label>Company (Disabled)</label>
            <input ng-model="user.company" disabled>
          </md-input-container>
          <md-datepicker ng-model="user.submissionDate" md-placeholder="Enter date">
          </md-datepicker>
        </div>
        <div layout-gt-sm="row">
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>First name</label>
            <input ng-model="user.firstName">
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>Long Last Name That Will Be Truncated And 3 Dots (Ellipsis) Will Appear At The End</label>
            <input ng-model="theMax">
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
          <label>Address</label>
          <input ng-model="user.address">
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block">
          <input ng-model="user.address2" placeholder="Address 2">
        </md-input-container>
        <div layout-gt-sm="row">
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>City</label>
            <input ng-model="user.city">
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
            <label>State</label>
            <md-select ng-model="user.state">
              <md-option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.abbrev}}">
                {{state.abbrev}}
              </md-option>
            </md-select>
          </md-input-container>
</form>
```